# How to pass parameters to jsreport to generate report based on the paramter

Tags: mysql, node.js, jsreport

This is the code to generate report using jsreport . I want to generate the report by passing a  input parameter to jsreport.

```
var express= require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request=require('request');

router.get('/' ,function(req,res,next){
var shortid=req.query.shortid;
var preview =req.query.preview;

var data={ 
template:{'shortid':shortid , "recipe" : "html"},
options:{
    preview:preview
}
}
var options={
uri:'http://localhost:5488/api/report',
method:'post',
json:data
//how to pass parameter here like uri,method. 
}
request(options).pipe(res);
});
module.exports=router;
```

I want to pass the parameter for a mysql query in the script of jsreport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the parameter through input data or attach it to options property

```
router.get('/' ,function(req,res,next){
  var shortid=req.query.shortid;
  var preview =req.query.preview;

  var data={ 
    template:{'shortid':shortid , "recipe" : "html"},
    options:{
        preview:preview
    },
    data: {
      paramA: 'foo'
    }
  }
  var options={
  uri:'http://localhost:5488/api/report',
  method:'post',
  json:data
  //how to pass parameter here like uri,method. 
  }
  request(options).pipe(res);
});
```

Then you can reach the parameter in the script on `req.data.paramA`. (if using jsreport < 1.0, reach it on global `request` object)

```
function beforeRender(req, res, done) {
  var paramA = req.data.paramA
  ...
  done()
}
```

Comment: i am getting below error when executing template in jsreport `Error occured - Error during rendering report: evalmachine.<anonymous>:28
    var param = req.param.paramA;
                         ^
Cannot read property 'paramA' of undefined
Stack - Error: evalmachine.<anonymous>:28
    var param = req.param.paramA;
                         ^`

Comment: There is `req.data.paramA` in my sample

Comment: how can i download js report at runtime

Comment: i want to show param value in html page in jsreport ,req.param.paramA  in this how to  bind  paramA value in html  , I tried {{paramA}} in html its not display any value